# $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ where $f(x)$ is linear and $g(x)$ is either strictly convex or strictly concave

Tags: calculus, limits

I am currently working on a problem where I am interested in the limit of a ratio of functions,
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}.$$
It is known that $f(x)$ is linearily increasing, e.g., $f(x) = x$, while $g(x)$ is either strictly convex or strictly concave.

Intuitively, (but possible incorrectly) it seems to me that, for the case when $g(x)$ is strictly convex, the ratio should tend to $0$ in the limit. Is this a well-known result or is there a good way to show this?

For the second case, when $g(x)$ is concave, is it possible to say anything at all about the limit? To me, it seems that it is not, but that more information is required about the limit of $g(x)$ itself to say something conclusive about the limit of the ratio.

Many thanks,

Comment: For the first case, consider $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-\ln|x|$. Then $$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=-\infty.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit can be different from $0$. Actually it can be any real number $m$. Consider for example $f(x)=mx$ and $g(x)=x-\arctan(x)$ which is strictly convex for $x>0$ (or $g(x)=x+\arctan(x)$ for a strictly concave one). Then
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=m.$$
It can be also $\pm \infty$. Take $f(x)=\mp x$ and $g(x)=-\arctan(x)$.

Comment: Very elegant, thank you. Would it make a difference of the following restrictions where added: First, $x \geq 0, f(x) \geq 0, g(x) > 0$ and, second, $g(x)$ is monotonous and continuous?

Comment: In that case the limit is any non negative number. Note that $g(x)=x-\arctan(x)$ is increasing , continuous and positive for $x>0$.